# Option of Dropdown is not display in kendo grid popup template

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I try to create dropdown into kendo grid edit popup tempate.but i unable to get value of dropdown into popup tempate.how to get it using kendo grid popup?

kendo field detail is describe below

```
{ field: "PaymentMode", title: "Payment Mode", width: 150, editor: paymentModeDropDownEditor, template: "#:AvailablePaymentMode#", hidden: true },
```

At Edit Event code is written below

```
 edit: function (e) {

  var formTypeData = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                data: [
                    { Text: "Cheque", Value: "0" },
                    { Text: "Cash", Value: "1" },
                ]
            });
function paymentModeDropDownEditor(container, options) {
                $('<input required data-text-field="Text" id="paymentMode" data-value-field="Value" data-bind="value:PaymentMode"/>')
                    .appendTo(container)
                    .kendoDropDownList({
                        autoBind: true,
                        dataSource: formTypeData,
                        change: onChange,
                    });
            }

            function onChange(e) {
                var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item);
                if (dataItem.Text == "Cash") {
                    $("input[name='ChequeReferenceNo']").hide();
                    $("label[for='ChequeReferenceNo']").hide();

                    $("input[name='BankName']").hide();
                    $("label[for='BankName']").hide();
                }
                else {
                    $("input[name='ChequeReferenceNo']").show();
                    $("label[for='ChequeReferenceNo']").show();

                    $("input[name='BankName']").show();
                    $("label[for='BankName']").show();
                }
            };
```

Kendo grid popup template script is written below

```
<script id="InvoiceUpdatePopup_editor" type="text/x-kendo-template">

  <input name="paymentMode" data-bind="value:AvailablePaymentMode" data-value-field="value" data-text-field="text" data-role="dropdownlist" />

<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its not as per your query but  have implemented using editable template as below:

Grid --

```
Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("PopupEditView"))
```

Grid Model :-

```
 .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(p => p.ID);            
            model.Field(p => p.Role).DefaultValue(ViewData["defaultCategory"] as UserRole);
        }
```

PopupEditView-

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.Role)
                    .DataValueField("Id")                                        
                    .DataTextField("RoleName")
                    .SelectedIndex(Model.Role.Id)                    
                    //.Value(Model.Role.RoleName)
                    //.Events(e => e.("onDataBound"))
                    .BindTo(ViewData["Category"] as IEnumerable<UserRole>)
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 280px;" })
        )
```

Controller--

```
ViewData["Category"] = list;
ViewData["defaultCategory"] = list.FirstOrDefault();
```

let me know how it worked for you.

Comment: I am happy that you help me but i have only two static option in my dropdown and i want to display dropdown using kendo popup template